# Twitter API with urllib2 in python

Tags: python, twitter

I want to use the Twitter API in Python to lookup user ids from name using the lookup method. I have done similar requests simply using

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://search.twitter.com...')
```

but for this one I need authentication. I don't think I can do it through the Google python twitter API because it doesn't have the lookup method. Any ideas how can I can auth with urllib2??

Answer (score 4):

You'd probably be better off using one of the actual Python libraries for the Twitter API:

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#python

Answer (score 3):

Use [`urllib2.Request`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#request-objects) to define the complete HTTP header:

```
request = urllib2.Request( 'http://twitter.com/...' )
request.add_header( 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode( username + ':' + password ) )
response = urllib2.urlopen( request )
```

Note however that basic authorization will be disabled soon on twitter and you'll need to migrate to OAuth. [Twitter API Wiki](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/OAuth-Examples) has some examples on that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the tweepy API.

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy

Examples here: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) library, this is the code to lookup user IDs by name:

```
from twython import Twython
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET,OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
print twitter.show_user(screen_name=USER_NAME)["id"]
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication can be done with various of Twitter API wrapper libraries. A full list of wrapper API is listed in [Twitter Developer Page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries).

Whatever the library is, you will have to implement OAuth authentication. This is sample code using [Python Twitter Tool](http://mike.verdone.ca/twitter/).

```
from twitter import *

MY_TWITTER_CREDS = os.path.expanduser('~/.my_app_credentials')
if not os.path.exists(MY_TWITTER_CREDS):
    oauth_dance("My App Name", CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
                MY_TWITTER_CREDS)

oauth_token, oauth_secret = read_token_file(MY_TWITTER_CREDS)

twitter = Twitter(auth=OAuth(
    oauth_token, oauth_secret, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))

# Now search with Twitter
rel = t.search.tweets(q='whatever')['statuses']
# Now do whatever you want with rel object
```