# How can I go about getting the JSON from a https link using Python?

Tags: python, json, ssl, https, urllib2

I am learning Python, and I want to start using Twitter's streaming API. I know how to build a very basic application that reads the contents of a page using `urllib2` and have done this successfully in the past. However, the secure connection `https://` that this particular Twitter streaming API requires doesn't appear to work with urllib2.

I have tried to fetch the JSON from the following link: `https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?locations=-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8`

By writing the following:

```
import urllib2
url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?locations=-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8"
print urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

The traceback, though, says I am not authorized; I presumed this is because of the HTTPS SSL connection, and research supported this. So I guess my question is what is the best way to go about getting the JSON from a link requiring such SSL connection? I also tried curl, but only get error 401 again.

Below is the traceback in its entirety.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 126, in urlopen   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 400, in open   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 513, in http_response   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 438, in error   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 372, in _call_chain   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 521, in http_error_default urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401:
>   Unauthorized

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The API probably requires an OAuth token or other API key.

Comment: Ah. It does say that it requires a Twitter user to be logged in. I suppose that is why the stream works when I type the url into my browser (because I am logged into Twitter). It does not require OAuth, so could I just add my login credentials to the header of my Python file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others mention, you need to authorize. Here's how to do it:

See [Twitter API with urllib2 in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833632/twitter-api-with-urllib2-in-python)

```
import urllib2
import base64

request = urllib2.Request( 'https://stream.twitter.com...' )
request.add_header( 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode( username + ':' + password ) )
response = urllib2.urlopen( request )
```

Comment: Thank you! I just tried that answer from the question you linked to and it seemed to work (terminal seems to be processing, though I don't know how long this should take – print the response upon reading it)

Comment: The problem with that approach is that it will work, but it won't be secure, since `urllib2` doesn't make any verification of the certificate or the host name.

Comment: @Bruno ... I guess it's insecure if you're paranoid that someone is impersonating twitter or sniffing your requests to the twitter api. http://thejosephturner.com/blog/2011/03/19/https-certificate-verification-in-python-with-urllib2/ has a workaround

Comment: It's insecure if there's a man-in-the-middle, which is one of the things HTTPS aims to protect against (beside passive eavesdropping).

Comment: @Bruno. Right, that's what I said ("someone impersonating twitter or sniffing your requests"). Anyway, follow the link if you want https.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the SSL connection that's not authorizing, its that you haven't explicitly authorized with the system before making this call. You need to perform some sort of authorization with the server before making your request.